# PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused (Ubuntu 16.04, Rails 5, Capistrano)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

When deploying a Rails 5 app to Ubunbtu 16.04.3 (Digitalocean VPS), when running `cap production deploy --trace` I'm getting the following error:

.

***Terminal***

```
$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate
rake aborted!

PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "138.68.6.26" and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

/home/deploy/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
/home/deploy/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
/home/deploy/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
/home/deploy/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:695:in...
/home/deploy/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:220:in…
/home/deploy/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:38:in …
/home/deploy/my-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-
...
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
cap aborted!
```

.

***Gemfile***

```
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.7', '>= 3.7.1'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.2'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
end
```

.

***Capfile***

```
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.4.1'

require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/passenger'
```

.

***config/deploy.rb***

```
set :application, "my-app"
set :repo_url, "git@github.com:username/my-app.git"

set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/my-app'

append :linked_files, "config/database.yml", "config/secrets.yml"
append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "vendor/bundle", "public/system", "public/uploads"
```

.

***config/deploy/production.rb***

```
server '138.68.6.26', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app db web}
```

.

On the server, I've already made the symlinked files `/home/deploy/my-app/shared/config/database.yml` and `/home/deploy/my-app/shared/config/secrets.yml` and removed them from my repo. I also git ignored them as well.

.

***database.yml***

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: 138.68.6.26
  database: my-app
  username: deploy
  password: password
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
```

.

***secrets.yml***

```
production:
  secret_key_base: 9b865db3b261f66576ef6b2a...
```

.

I also set up an Ubuntu system user named postgres and created a database user named deploy. I named the database correctly as indicated within the `database.yml` file. I've searched all over the place an cannot get this to work. Most of the answers are for debugging locally. This is for a deployment.

Comment: On your DB host, can you run `netstat -nltp | grep postgres` and see if postgres is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0:5432) ?

Comment: Here is the output for that command: `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16373/postgres`

Comment: Ok, that's the problem, your Postgres server is listening on the localhost interface only and not accessible from outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I had the wrong ip address in the `database.yml` file. I had it set to my host ip (138.68.6.26) when it should have been set to the local ip (127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to this server via psql, if you can't, the problem is in your postgresql server config. (Do this from the app's server)

> psql -h 138.68.6.26 -U deploy my-app

Answer (score 0):

Your Postgres server is configured to listen on the `localhost` interface only and hence not available from the outside.

To configure Postgres to allow external TCP connections, make these changes:

1) set `listen_addresses` to `*` in /etc/postgresql/<>/main/postgresql.conf

2) set the access permissions in /etc/postgresql/<>/main/pg_hba.conf to allow TCP connections from external IPs

Just make sure you got a firewall like UFW set up to prevent arbitrary hosts to connect to your database.